# It keeps returning NaN(Not a Number) in my console

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

here's the **object** with **arrays**:

```
const studentGrades = [
    [{ studentID: 1, Q1: 89.3, Q2: 91.2, Q3: 93.3, Q4: 89.8 }],
    [{ studentID: 2, Q1: 69.2, Q2: 71.3, Q3: 76.5, Q4: 81.9 }],
    [{ studentID: 3, Q1: 95.7, Q2: 91.4, Q3: 90.7, Q4: 85.6 }],
    [{ studentID: 4, Q1: 86.9, Q2: 74.5, Q3: 83.3, Q4: 86.1 }],
    [{ studentID: 5, Q1: 70.9, Q2: 73.8, Q3: 80.2, Q4: 81.8 }]
];
```

I tried doing the following, it must have 1 decimal point and must be a number:

```
studentGrades.forEach( function(grade){
    
    grade.average = grade.Q1 + grade.Q2 + grade.Q3 + grade.Q4/4
    parseFloat(grade.average).toFixed(1);
    
});
```

But it keeps returning **NaN** in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is Array inside an array, hence you need to add `grade[0]`

```js
const studentGrades = [
    [{ studentID: 1, Q1: 89.3, Q2: 91.2, Q3: 93.3, Q4: 89.8 }],
    [{ studentID: 2, Q1: 69.2, Q2: 71.3, Q3: 76.5, Q4: 81.9 }],
    [{ studentID: 3, Q1: 95.7, Q2: 91.4, Q3: 90.7, Q4: 85.6 }],
    [{ studentID: 4, Q1: 86.9, Q2: 74.5, Q3: 83.3, Q4: 86.1 }],
    [{ studentID: 5, Q1: 70.9, Q2: 73.8, Q3: 80.2, Q4: 81.8 }]
];

studentGrades.forEach( function(grade){
    
    grade[0].average = (grade[0].Q1 + grade[0].Q2 + grade[0].Q3 + grade[0].Q4)/4;
    parseFloat(grade[0].average).toFixed(1);
    
});

console.log(studentGrades);
```

Answer (score 1):

studentGrades is an array of arrays, you should remove the brackets outside the actual studentGrade if they are not necessary and make it like this :

```
const studentGrades = [
{ studentID: 1, Q1: 89.3, Q2: 91.2, Q3: 93.3, Q4: 89.8 },
{ studentID: 2, Q1: 69.2, Q2: 71.3, Q3: 76.5, Q4: 81.9 },
{ studentID: 3, Q1: 95.7, Q2: 91.4, Q3: 90.7, Q4: 85.6 },
{ studentID: 4, Q1: 86.9, Q2: 74.5, Q3: 83.3, Q4: 86.1 },
{ studentID: 5, Q1: 70.9, Q2: 73.8, Q3: 80.2, Q4: 81.8 }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add [0] to grade because your studentGrades is a array of arrays.

```
studentGrades.forEach( function(grade){
        grade.average = (grade[0].Q1 + grade[0].Q2 + grade[0].Q3 + grade[0].Q4) / 4;
        parseFloat(grade.average).toFixed(1);
    });
```